# URL Scheme doesn't work when app not backgrounded

Tags: iphone, ios, appdelegate, url-scheme

I am trying to launch my app with a custom URL scheme.  If the app is backgrounded, all is fine.  If the app is not backgrounded, it launches, and the launch screen never disappears, eventually it gets killed by iOS for taking too long.  I have extensively debugged this, and cannot figure out the problem.  I have even removed everything from my application `didFinishLauinchingWithOptions` to make sure that nothing was stopping it there.  This is my altered code, all I am asking is that it opens and gives me a blank window, but won't even do that.  Just hangs on launch screen.

```
if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey]) {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    self.window.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];

    return YES;
}
```

URL Scheme in plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb23423444322</string>
            <string>test</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Comment: Can you please post the contents of this method: `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`

Comment: This method is not being called.  I placed an NSLog in it and it doesn't get that far

Comment: Can you show us the "URL types" items in your Info.plist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you handling what happens when your application responds to the URL Scheme. You should be use this delegate method in your App Delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{   
     // Do what you need here

     return YES;
}
```

Check the contents of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. The code in this method should not be commented out. Also it looks like you have a conditional in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. This is most likely while the app is hanging on startup.

Comment: This is not even being called when the app is launched the first time

Comment: When you say launched the first time do you mean you are tap the icon to start the app or is it still being opened via the URL Scheme? Also post the code you have in the method above. Also if you are responding to a URL Scheme then the method above is definitely being called.

Comment: It is being opened via URL scheme, but it is not backgrounded, it is closed out of multitasking.  I have put an NSLog in the beginning of this method, it does not fire

Comment: Does the app launch without any issues (tapping on the icon)? Also can you run the app and see if you are getting any errors in the console.

Comment: App launches fine tapping on icon, the only time it doesn't launch is when not backgrounded, and opened with URL, no errors on console

Comment: Is didFinishLauinchingWithOptions: being called? Also please post the contents of this method.

Comment: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is being called, that is what is posted above, I commented everything else out to test this. The entire method is posted in the question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34948/discussion-between-dana0550-and-jeffn)